# Dealing with the boundary between async and synchronous code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am trying to write some asynchronous c# code, and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the resources out there for `async` vs `.Wait()`.  I have read many of the threads and websites, but somehow I'm still not sure how/why I should not use a wait. Goal of my program is this:

1. Kick off something asynchronously
2. Do some work
3. Wait for #1 to complete.
4. Do more work that requires #1 to be complete for

With tasks I have:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Task t = DoWork();
    DoMoreWork();
    t.Wait();
    DoWorkThatNeedsT();
}

public Task DoWork()
{
    return Task.Run(() => {Thread.Sleep(1000);});
}
```

as far as I can tell, using async await in this instance just involves changing DoWork() to the following:

```
public async Task DoWork()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => {Thread.Sleep(1000);});
}
```

Then I still have a `.Wait()` in the calling method.  Is this supposed to get the benefits of thread-less asynchrony?  Is there a different way I am supposed to be implementing this?

Comment: What are you doing asynchronously?  Otherwise there is no point in using async.  Also, `Task.Run()` is NOT a solution, as it spins up another thread for no reason.

Comment: whatever was in the task.run is done asynchronously.  In this case, it is just sleeping for a bit.  In my actual program, it is deleting some files and running an external program.

Comment: Then you don't need async/await... what you are describing is NOT what is to be used for.  Instead use a background worker/task.run.  I'll explain below.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. There are lots of Q&A on Stack Overflow addressing calling `async` from sync/blocking code. Including scenarios rooted at `Main()` (which isn't inherently asynchronous). But in the code you have above, your proposed change to make `DoWork()` an `async` method seems pointless; it adds absolutely nothing to the overall implementation. It also has _nothing_ to do with the call to `Wait()` in the main method, which is what you seem to be asking about. Please fix your question; explain what you've read and what _specifically_ you aren't understanding.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was reading the documentation pages/SO questions that say that you should hardly ever use .Wait() and instead use await.  I wasn't sure how that guidance applied to this situation (or how to implement it properly without .Wait()), hence the question.  It appears based upon the comments that the code should be left as-is without async/await.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described is not what async/await is used for. Async/await is used to release threads back to the operating system to be used by other systems while the system waits for something it does not have control over (for example, waiting for a sql statement to complete on a remote system).

What you want is to run task(s) in parallel with other code.  Use [Task.Run](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) but don't worry about async/await, because you have nothing you're really waiting for.

[Stephen Cleary - There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) is a great read to understand when to use async/await.